# Accessing authenticated Google Cloud Endpoints API from Google Apps Script

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to pull some data into a Google sheets spreadsheet from an API that's been built using Google Cloud Endpoints. Here is the API declaration:

```
@Api(
        name = "myendpoint", 
        namespace = 
            @ApiNamespace
                (
                    ownerDomain = "mydomain.com", 
                    ownerName = "mydomain.com", 
                    packagePath = "myapp.model"
                ),
         scopes = {SCOPES},
         clientIds = {ANDROID_CLIENT_ID, WEB_CLIENT_ID, API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID},
         audiences = {WEB CLIENT_ID}
)
```

The method I'm trying to access has authentication enabled by means of the user parameter in the API declaration:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "ping", httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET, path = "ping")
public StringResponse getPing(User user) throws OAuthRequestException {

    CheckPermissions(user);//throws an exception if the user is null or doesn't have the correct permissions

    return new StringResponse("pong");
}
```

This works fine when using the generated client libraries or the gapi js library. However AFAIK I can't use those js libraries in Apps Script.

I've got an OAuth2 flow working using the apps-script-oauth2 library from [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2), and I'm pretty much using the default setup for creating the service

```
function getService() {
  // Create a new service with the given name. The name will be used when
  // persisting the authorized token, so ensure it is unique within the
  // scope of the property store.
  return OAuth2.createService(SERVICE_NAME)

  // Set the endpoint URLs, which are the same for all Google services.
  .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth')
  .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')

  // Set the client ID and secret, from the Google Developers Console.
  .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
  .setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)

  // Set the name of the callback function in the script referenced
  // above that should be invoked to complete the OAuth flow.
  .setCallbackFunction('ruggedAuthCallback')

  // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
  .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())

  // Set the scopes to request (space-separated for Google services).
  .setScope(SCOPES)

  // Below are Google-specific OAuth2 parameters.

  // Sets the login hint, which will prevent the account chooser screen
  // from being shown to users logged in with multiple accounts.
  .setParam('login_hint', Session.getActiveUser().getEmail())

  // Requests offline access.
  .setParam('access_type', 'offline')

  // Forces the approval prompt every time. This is useful for testing,
  // but not desirable in a production application.
  .setParam('approval_prompt', 'auto')

  //.setParam('include_granted_scopes', 'true');
}
```

These are my methods for accessing the APIs

```
function getDriveDocs() {
  return executeApiMethod('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/','files?maxResults=10');
}

function pingServer(){
  return executeApiMethod('https://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/api/myendpoint/v1/','ping');
}

function executeApiMethod(apiUrl, method)
{
  //var url = ;
  var url = apiUrl + method;
  var service = getRuggedService();
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'method': 'get',
    'headers': {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
    }
  });
}
```

The getDriveDocs() method works perfectly, so I know my auth flow is working correctly. Also, if I call an unauthenticated method in my API I get the correct response. However, when I call the authenticated 'ping' method, the 'user' parameter is always null. Am I missing something in the fetch call? Everything I've read so far seems to suggest that setting

```
Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
```

should be enough.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a simple mistake - I had created a new oauth2 credential in the google dev console and had not added the new client id to the API declaration. Here is the working API declaration:

```
@Api(
        name = "myendpoint", 
        namespace = 
            @ApiNamespace
                (
                    ownerDomain = "mydomain.com", 
                    ownerName = "mydomain.com", 
                    packagePath = "myapp.model"
                ),
         scopes = {SCOPES},
         clientIds = {ANDROID_CLIENT_ID, WEB_CLIENT_ID, API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID, GAPPS_CLIENT_ID},
         audiences = {WEB CLIENT_ID}
    )
```

Comment: This is from the Java file that defines the API and is deployed to Google Cloud Platform